# Issues in installing a package in R

Tags: r

I was trying to install a package in R. However, it shows the following error

```
installing *source* package ‘glasso’ ...
** package ‘glasso’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 This package has only been tested with gfortran.
 So some checks are needed for a Fortran 90 compiler.
 R_HOME is /usr/local/Cellar/r/2.15.1/R.framework/Resources
    Unsupported Fortran 90 compiler or Fortran 90
    compilers unavailable! Stop!
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘glasso’
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: You don't give much information, but maybe you should try installing gfortran?

Comment: @Roland. I am running Mac. When I go to console and run gfortran it says i686-apple-darwin11-gfortran-4.2.1: no input files which means it is installed. So why isn't R able to find it? Do I need to do something

Comment: See, this is important information, which you should edit into your question. Could it be possible that you are trying to install the package version for R 3.0.1 in R 2.15.1? I suggest that you update R.

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed the tools necessary to build packages from source. Specifically, you're missing the fortran compiler. You probably need to install Apple's Xcode development tools.

Comment: Specifically, that looks like a very old version of gfortran. Do some [reading](http://r.research.att.com/tools/).

Comment: I made this little guid thingy for a package that used to require Mac tools and it may be helpful: http://trinker.github.io/qdap_install/installation.html Specifically look at the links under Mac Users.

Comment: @joran. I have Xcode installed. May be I need to update it. I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions of OSX, XCode, Fortran, R and the target package must all be compatible. (And you should have included all of those version numbers in your question.) At the moment the only thing we can tell is that you have an out-of-date version of R. Simon Urbanek provides [a GNU Fortran compiler at the ATT Research website](http://r.research.att.com/gfortran-4.2.3.dmg). Your machine appears improperly set up to properly dispatch to the GNU FORTRAN that you do find with your console test. If it was installed with MacPorts or Fink, it may not be in the proper directory for the R Makefile directive to XCode/make to find it.

Since the default behavior of installing a source package is to retrieve the current version of that package, you might be getting a source package that is properly mated to R 3.0.1 but not to R 2.15.1. There are [older versions of glasso in the Archives](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/glasso/glasso_1.6.tar.gz) if you decide to go that route.

But why not update to R 3.0.1 and use the current binary version? There is no apparent need for a source installation, and you appear not to have the right tools or the right skillset to do this effectively. (I'm not trying to insult you, since I struggle with these issues myself.)